# Create dynamic primary key constraint with JOOQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, dynamic-sql, jooq

I am using JOOQ(newbie in JOOQ) to create the database at runtime using Rest API in my spring boot project.
In one of the case I need to create a table with a composite primary key which can be combination of multiple columns.
I am using the below piece of code to create constraint -

```java
ArrayList<Constraint> constraints = new ArrayList<>();
constraints.add(constraint(name("pk_" + tableName))
.primaryKey(field("column1"), field("column2")));
```

I already have `List<Field<?>>` which will be working as the composite primary key.
How can I make this dynamic as the primary key constraint can support n number of columns?
Is there any way I can directly provide the field list in the `.primarykey()` API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual overloads for `primaryKey(Collection<? extends Field<?>>)` that one may expect in such a case are missing from the constraint API. I've create a feature request for jOOQ 3.15: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11816

You can just use [`ConstraintTypeStep.primaryKey(Field<?>...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ConstraintTypeStep.html#primaryKey(org.jooq.Field...)) using standard JDK [`Collection.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) methods:

```java
List<Field<?>> list = ...

// Pre Java 11
constraints.add(constraint(...).primaryKey(list.toArray(new Field<?>[0])));

// Using new JDK 11 API
constraints.add(constraint(...).primaryKey(list.toArray(Field<?>[]::new)));
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue while creating an index as well.I have tableName in String and `List<Field<?>>` can you please provide a solution for this as well. I am using below function call -                                  
 `dslContext.createIndex().on(name(tableName),
 name("column1), name("column2");).execute()`

Comment: Just remove the `;`

Comment: @luks-eder `;` was a typo I need to create an index with multiple dynamic columns. I also have the `List<Field<?>>` with me for the columns.

Comment: Just use `toArray()` again. Be sure to use the `on(Table<?>, Field<?>...)` method. There's no `on(Name, Field<?>...)` method.